# Android: thread synchronization: waiting for a dialog to close to proceed

Tags: android

In an android project I have a function foo which needs to perform a sequence
of operations in sequence. Inside foo I would like to call showDialog to display a
dialog and wait. Then from showDialog when the user clicks an entry I would
like the dialog to notify() the foo function so that it may continue. I do not
want foo to continue execution until the dialog tells it so. So far I have
come up with the following which for some reason does not seem to work:

```
  class FooActivity {

    synchronized void foo(String param) {

      try {

          showDialog(DIALOG_SELECT_FOO);

          wait();

          doNextThing(param);

        }

      } catch (Exception e) { }

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

      switch (id) {

        case DIALOG_SELECT_FOO:

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

          // ...

          builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

              synchronized(FooActivity.this) {

                FooActivity.this.notify();

              }

            }

          });

          return builder.create();

      }

      // should never get here

      return null;

    }

  }
```

Basically, I am not seeing the dialog at all. I think this is because wait() is
being called before the dialog gets a chance to run. Does the dialog run on the
same thread as the caller? Any idea on how to fix this code?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a [handler](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html).